# Sudo, no access to user files

Tags: debian, sudo

I  installed the newest version of Debian and have no access to my own files when using the `sudo` command:

- `ls` -> shows files in my home directory
- `sudo ls` -> permission denied

My user is part of the sudoers group and has the following entry in 
the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
user1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I never had this problem before when using Ubuntu.

My home directory is on an NFSv4 filesystem.

Comment: Your problem is mst probably lying here --> **My homedir is mounted over the network as nfs4**. Your files' ownership and permissions are governed by the NFS server, not your user ID on the local box, even if you are the `root` user, locally.

Comment: Yes that would make sense, is there any possibilty to fix this issue ?

Comment: Not on your local machine. NFS server will need to be modified for client side `root` access, but it is a very big security headache and if you are in a corporate environment, I can almost guarantee, your storage admins are going to balk at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory is on an NFS-mounted filesystem.  Likely, the NFS server has exported it with the `root_squash` option (default on most systems), meaning that for access to this filesystem, the `root` user is mapped to the `nobody` user, and is thus subject to the permissions for 'others' for the directory.

Possible actions:

1. Don't use `root` for accessing this directory.  For example, if you're writing a script to scan users' home directories, `sudo` from root to each user in turn to examine their home:

   ```sh
   for user in `getent passwd | grep ':/home' | cut -d : -f1`
   do
        sudo -u "$user" \
            "$process_directory" "`getent passwd $user | cut -d : -f6`"
   done
   ```

   (I split the `sudo` line to separate options from the command)
2. Change the permissions on the directory to allow read and search by the `nobody` user (e.g. `chmod go+rx`).  This may or may not be acceptable to you; you will probably want to ensure that sensitive files such as `~/.ssh/` and cache directories are not world-readable.
3. Change the exports on the server to remove the `root_squash` option.  On Debian, this means editing `/etc/exports` to add `no_root_squash` to the list of options:

   ```sh
   srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
   ```

   This will then allow `root` to access all files on that filesystem regardless of permissions, just as if the filesystem were local.

Comment: Thank you, how exactly do I sudo from root to a certain user ?

Comment: You can use `sudo -u username command` - for example `sudo -u rtm ls ~rtm/` to list the content of user *rtm*'s file as *rtm*.  If you first open a shell as *root* with the `sudo -i` command, you can use `su username` or `su - username` to become the user *username* (the `-` options gives you the user's environment).  *root* is not prompted for password when `su`'ing to another user.  You can also use `su` with `sudo`, eg. `sudo su -c 'ls ~rtm' rtm` - this may show you clearer that you first become *root* - then another user.

Comment: Use of `sudo` is of course dependent on the entries in the /etc/sudoers file...  "user  ALL = (ALL) ALL" actually means that *user* may run ALL-commands as ALL-users (including *root*) on ALL-machines.  The entries are "username  machines = (run_as_user) commands".  So if your user (or root) are not allowed to run commands as any other user, this won't  work.  If you first become *root* however, you can still use `su user` to become any other user without being prompted for password.  You just can't do it with only `sudo` in one go...