# Edited sudoers, but `sudo ls` fails

Tags: permissions, sudo, ls, root

A user has been added with root access in the `/etc/sudoers` but, it seems that it can not run `sudo` commands.

```
[root@compute-0-0 ~]# cat /etc/sudoers
root     ALL=(ALL)      ALL
hduser   ALL=(ALL)      ALL
[root@compute-0-0 ~]# sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -L | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user name] [-u user name|#uid] [-g
        groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
        name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
        name|#uid] file ...
[root@compute-0-0 ~]# su - hduser
[hduser@compute-0-0 ~]$ ls
bio  hadoop-2.7.2  hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz  protobuf-2.5.0  protobuf-2.5.0.tar.gz  
[hduser@compute-0-0 ~]$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for hduser:
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
[hduser@compute-0-0 ~]$
```

What is the reason?

Comment: What happens if `hduser` does `cd /tmp` before the `sudo ls` ?

Comment: What password are you using for sudo as hduser? Root password, or hduser's?

Comment: @Stephen Harris: Yes you are right. It works

Comment: @FarazX: Yes, hduser's password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is not a `sudo` problem, but a `root` permission problem.

The filesystem that has `hduser`'s home directory is not local to the machine and doesn't grant `root` permission to it.  So when you did `su - hduser` you automatically changed to that directory, so `sudo ls` tried to run the `ls` command as `root` and *that* is where the error came from.

This may help you solve that problem: [Sudo, no access to user files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292897/sudo-no-access-to-user-files/292907#292907)

Comment: Does that mean I have to add `no_root_squash` to the nodes (the last parenthesis?`/export 10.10.10.1(rw,async,no_root_squash) 10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0(rw,async)
`

Comment: If you want `root` to access the files in `/export`, yes.  But you have to do it for all the `(rw,...)` options on all the hosts you want `root` to see.  This is no longer a `sudo` question and may be better asked in a new question.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not only for `ls`. The question is about running a sudo command. For example `hduser` wants to run `mount` command on the nodes.

Comment: And that'll work fine because you're not trying to access the home directory.  For safety the user _should_ `cd /` before hand, but it shouldn't stop the `sudo` from running if they forget.  Only commands that impact `/export` (or other NFS directories) will be affected by `root_squash`.

Comment: OK. I got it.... `cd / && sudo ls` works.