# Running sudo command for a user on the nodes (Rocks)

Tags: centos, sudo

Previously, I asked a question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297988/edited-sudoers-but-sudo-ls-fails) that a user which is in the `sudoers` file, want to run some `sudo` commands on the nodes. The problem, is that with the `sudo` command, it cannot access its home. Though it can access other folders.

So, on the frontend, we have

```
# cat /etc/exports
/export 10.10.10.1(rw,async,no_root_squash) 10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0(rw,async)
```

Now, please see that `hduser` uses ssh to login to the compute node. It can run `sudo` command to list `/` but not its home.

```
[hduser@compute-0-0 /]$ ls /home/hduser/
bio  hadoop-2.7.2  hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz  usr
[hduser@compute-0-0 /]$ sudo ls
bin   etc      lib         media  net   root     share  sys  var
boot  home     lib64       misc   opt   sbin     srv    tmp
dev   install  lost+found  mnt    proc  selinux  state  usr
[hduser@compute-0-0 /]$ sudo ls /home/hduser
ls: cannot open directory /home/hduser: Permission denied
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, `root` is denied because of `root_squash`, which is the default export behaviour.  In this mode remote access from `root` is mapped to `nobody`.

If all the nodes are meant to be equivalent with no uniqueness then you should  simplify the export

```
/export 10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0(rw,async,no_root_squash)
```

After making this change, `exportfs -a`.

If this doesn't immediately solve the problem then the client may need to be restarted (`umount`, `mount` the relevant filesystem, or reboot).

Comment: So that is Rocks! If I change that file, I think I have to run `rocks sync config` and I think the content of `/etc/exports` is the default one. So, I want to be sure that modifying that line has no effect on the system configuration.

Comment: It will have no effect on host `10.10.10.1` and the other hosts on that subnet will now have `root` level access to `/export` where they don't at the moment